# What can cause a process to stop being re-created?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows

We have a service written in C++ with some code in .NET via CLI. Because of a third party library that overrides memory on a data driven basis, we were forced to strip out the main processing code into a separate code path that is utilized as follows. When running the service EXE with a specific command line parameter, we can either run the whole service as a console app, bypassing the service parts or as a console app that only does the processing. In the main mode of operation, the service starts normally and uses createprocess to start it's own executable with a command line parameter, which skips the service initialization and goes strait to the processing part. The service thread then waits for the child process to finish and repeats this process as needed.

The problem we are experiencing is that the service fails to launch the command line version of itself after 1700 child process runs. If we are unlucky enough, the service also refuses to restart. No relevant processes are in memory when the service refuses to restart. When running the service in command line mode after the service failed, it continues for a further 1700 runs of the child process until it also fails. A system reboot is required to restore the working of the service/command line process. We are also getting error 322 - "The target device has insufficient resources to complete the operation." in the event log. We have already removed a Job kernel object that grouped the child process and the parent process into one unit so that when you terminate the parent, the child also terminates. This increased the 1700 limit by several thousand.

Is there any reason why windows would remember that a process ran and would penalize that process when it is re-run? It appears that processes run under different desktops or users are treated as separate processes in regards to this issue. When the service fails, the command line version can be run and will work for a while. Does this have something to do with the desktop heap? We never have more than two processes in memory at the same time. What type of windows functions can have a lasting effect on a process, the next time it is run under a certain desktop/user?

Comment: I had my share with desktop heap. See http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2014/02/04/155370.aspx perhaps You are also leaking desktop heap allocated objects. Registerwindowmessage is a good start to look after.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're leaking a kernel resource shared between the parent process and the child processes.  Perhaps at each launch of a child process the parent creates a handle to some resource and passes it (shared) to the child, expecting the child to close it ... but not closing it itself as it needs to?

The SysInternals utilities could help you diagnose this.  HandleEx, or Process Explorer to start, then dig in with Process Monitor.

Comment: Desktop heap allocated objects like Windows or window message registrations are usually invisible to these tools. You need to use a kernel debugger to monitor the current desktop heaps or You inject a kernel driver like dheapmon does http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2009/10/desktop-heap-monitor-vista-7/

Comment: @AloisKraus: it seems unlikely to be a desktop heap object in this context.  There's no reason for the parent to be creating desktop heap objects on a per-child basis, and any that the child creates should get cleaned up as normal.  Still worth checking, but I'd check for kernel objects first.